# spring+hibernate : Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: spring, hibernate, autowired

i did some search but i was unable to find out what's the problem.
I'm aware the problem come from a ClassNotFoundException but i can't solve it.

error : 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.it.service.applicationService com.it.controller.applicationController.applicationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

caused by :
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$1: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.it.service.applicationService com.it.controller.applicationController.applicationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

my conf :       version : 3.2.0.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

i autowired everything i need to (well, i think). here is my code :

DAO class:

```
    package com.it.dao;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.it.model.application;


    @Repository("applicationDao")
    public class applicationDaoImpl implements applicationDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}


public List<application> listeAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from application").list();
}

    }
```

Service class :

```
    package com.it.service;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import com.it.dao.applicationDao;
    import com.it.model.application;

    @Service("applicationService")
    public class applicationServiceImpl implements applicationService {

@Autowired
private applicationDao applicationDao;


@Transactional
public List<application> listeAll() {
    return applicationDao.listeAll();
}

    }
```

Controller class :

```
package com.it.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.it.model.application;
import com.it.service.applicationService;

@Controller
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.it.service")
public class applicationController {

@Autowired
private applicationService applicationService;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("application", new application());
    map.put("applicationList", applicationService.listeAll());

    return "application";
}
}
```

spring-servlet.xml :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    p:packagesToScan="com.it" 
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    />


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

<!-- Translates Hibernate exceptions to Spring Data Access Exceptions -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>
```

here i try several thing, localSessionFactoryBean, annotationfactorybean, hibernate 3 or 4 etc.. but none is working :(

also i have :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.it.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.it.dao" />
```

and services should be scanned by annotation but i tried to declare scan in xml as well.

If anyone can help me, it would be nice :)
Thanks you in advance,
Aure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `spring-orm` to your Maven Dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure your maven dependencies are being deployed, check out the first image in this answer: [servlet packages not importing after converting project to maven project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409149/servlet-packages-not-importing-after-converting-project-to-maven-project-in-ecli/16409211#16409211)

Comment: Thanks for your quick anwser, but nothing change. Even after downloading spring-orm :(

Comment: i don't have deployment assembly tab.

Comment: i did mvn eclipse:eclipse and jar downloaded. it now appears in eclipse as a jar in my project. pretty sure it's deployed.

Comment: @user2357614 Excellent, did that fix your issues?

Comment: kinda. now HibernateTransactionManager is bugging, im confused, HibernateTransactionManager is in the spring-orm too but it raise an ClassNotFoundException

Comment: any idea ? Invocation of init method of TransactionManager failed, i think my dataSource is correct in the hibernate-cfg.xml :/

Answer (score 0):

Where do you hand the hibernate.dialect to the sessionFactory? For a more complete view it would be helpful to see all parts of the configuration going into hibernate. So can you post your DataSource.
  But what I can say so far that the hibernate.dialect is a property that is mandatory to set. Besides the DataSource it is pretty much the only really essential configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.GenericDialect</property>
```

Try adding this to your sessionFactory Bean.