# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, maven

`org.springframework.spring-webmvc` [includes `spring-context`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.2.RELEASE) so I'm not sure why I'm not seeing `org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` in may application.

What am I missing?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your maven dependencies are included in the deployment assembly.  See: [servlet packages not importing after converting project to maven project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409149/servlet-packages-not-importing-after-converting-project-to-maven-project-in-ecli/16409211#16409211)